# Knockout and observable array mismatch

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Consider the following properties inside a viewmodel

```
self.allValues = ko.observableArray();
self.selectedValues = ko.observableArray();
```

On edit, `selectedValues` contains values coming from database. Here is the problem: `selectedValues` contains elements than are included on `allValues`, but they are **not** the same instances. They are the same from properties values point of view but are actually different objects.

This causes that every time knockout uses `indexOf` over `allValues` using objects from `selectedValues` always fails to find the object.

I'm using `selectedValues` on a `checked` binding but fails to check the correct elements included on this array.

```
<div class="vars-list" data-bind="foreach: allValues">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data...(etc) 
       checked: selelectedValues"  />
</div>
```

Is there any way for knockout to match objects by property values instead of memory address?

Comment: The checked binding internally uses `indexOf` to check which element is selected and this comparison is not configurable. So you have two options you create a custom binding based of the `checked` binding where you can have your custom comparison. Or when you're loading your `selectedValues` array instead of creating new object you lookup the item from the `allValues`. So the `selectedValues` will contains instances which are in the  `allValues` array. http://jsfiddle.net/NQYW9/

Comment: @nemesv: I'm currenlty following the lookup approach but seems a little dirty, that's why I wanted to know an alternative option. I'll check about the custom binding. Thanks!

Comment: Knockout feature: allow the comparison to be configurable.  I agree that the lookup approach is dirty.  I actually was struggling with a similar situation with a drop down list and I was referred to this post.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20411739/knockout-js-setting-selectedoption-to-an-object?noredirect=1#comment30493376_20411739

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a custom binding is one way to go. Here's a variation of the `checked` binding that uses a comparison function.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.checkedInArray = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "click", function() {
            var observable = valueAccessor(), 
                array = observable(), 
                checkedValue = allBindings.get('checkedValue'), 
                isChecked = element.checked, 
                comparer = allBindings.get('checkedComparer');

            for (var i = 0, n = array.length; 
                i < n && !comparer(array[i], checkedValue); 
                ++i) { }

            if (!isChecked && i < n) {
                observable.splice(i, 1);
            } else if (isChecked && i == n) {
                observable.push(checkedValue);
            }
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var array = valueAccessor()(), 
            checkedValue = allBindings.get('checkedValue'), 
            comparer = allBindings.get('checkedComparer');

        for (var i = 0, n = array.length;
            i < n && !comparer(array[i], checkedValue); 
            ++i) { }

        element.checked = (i < n);
    }
};
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/4mET9/

Comment: Hey, thanks! I'll be testing this as soon as I can and let you know how it goes.

Comment: This code saved my behind today. Can't thank you enough for it!