# Knockout.js Setting SelectedOption to an object

Tags: knockout.js

I'm on my first Knockout project and working trying to figure out the best way to handle this situation.

Hopefully this dumbed down example serves it's purpose.

I am trying to edit a 'project' object which has a property for 'employee'.

```
function Project(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = data.Name;
    self.Employee = data.Employee;
}

function Employee(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.ID = data.ID;
    self.Name = data.Name;
}
```

I first load up my project and then set the 'selectedEmployee'.

```
var me = new Employee ({ ID: 1, Name: 'Aaron'});

function vm() {
    var self = this;

    self.Project = ko.observable(new Project({ Name:'Knockout', Employee:me}));

    self.selectedEmployee = ko.observable(self.Project().Employee);

    self.employees = ko.observableArray([
                                        new Employee ({ID: 1,Name: 'Aaron'}),
                                        new Employee ({ID: 2,Name: 'George'}),
                                        new Employee ({ID: 3,Name: 'Ross'})
                                        ]);
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

I have a drop down list which holds a list of employees:

```
<select data-bind="options: employees, optionsText: 'Name',value: selectedEmployee, optionsCaption:'Pick Employee'"></select>
```

My Problem: The drop down list does not have an employee selected.  I'm guessing this is because the 'selectedEmployee' object and the Project.Employee object are not the same.

This example works:

```
var me = new Employee ({ ID: 1, Name: 'Aaron'});

function vm() {
    var self = this;

    self.Project = ko.observable(new Project({ Name:'Knockout', Employee:me}));

    self.selectedEmployee = ko.observable(self.Project().Employee);

    self.employees = ko.observableArray([
                                        me,
                                        new Employee ({ID: 2,Name: 'George'}),
                                        new Employee ({ID: 3,Name: 'Ross'})
                                        ]);
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

So, what is the best practice of making the 'Employee' on the project match what is in the drop down list?  Do I need to retrieve the Employee object from the list of 'employees' (based on ID) when I load it up?

I tried using an observable property for the EmployeeName (to use when displaying the value [read-only]) and EmployeeID (to use when selecting from the list), but the EmployeeName is not updated.

Seems like there should be an easy way to do this, but like I said, this is my first Knockout project.

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VSvW7/1/)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to do the by id lookup as in your send example. Or you can use a custom checked binding like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276692/knockout-and-observable-array-mismatch where you can provide a compare function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I'm going to provide the answer I came up with based on the comment by @nemesv.

Here's my HTML.  Notice I am setting the `options` to an array of objects.  The `optionsText` and `optionsValue` properties are set as you might expect.  My custom binding `selectById` is set to the selected object in my View Model.

```
<select data-bind="options: employees, 
            optionsText: 'Name',
            optionsValue: 'ID',                    
            selectById: selectedEmployee, 
            optionsCaption:'Pick Employee'">
</select>
<br><br>
Selected Employee:
<span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(selectedEmployee)"></span>
```

Here's my view model:

```
function Project(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = data.Name;
    self.Employee = data.Employee;
}

function Employee(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.ID = data.ID;
    self.Name = data.Name;
}

ko.bindingHandlers.selectById = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {    
        $(element).change(function() {
            var emps = ko.unwrap(allBindings.get('options'));
            var newSelectedValue = $(element).find("option:selected").val();
            var va = valueAccessor();
            if (!!newSelectedValue) {
                va(ko.utils.arrayFirst(emps, function(item) { return item.ID == newSelectedValue }));                                
            } 
            else va(null);                                
        });     
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var selectedItem = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());   
        $(element).val(selectedItem ? selectedItem.ID : '');        
    }
}

var me = new Employee({ ID: 1, Name: 'Aaron' });

function output(sender) {
    //console.warn($(arg.target));
    console.info('New Selected Value: ' + $(sender.target).find("option:selected").val());
}

function vm() {
    var self = this;

    self.Project = ko.observable(new Project({ Name: 'Knockout', Employee: me }));

    self.selectedEmployee = ko.observable(me);

    self.employees = ko.observableArray([
                                        new Employee({ ID: 1, Name: 'Aaron' }),
                                        new Employee({ ID: 2, Name: 'George' }),
                                        new Employee({ ID: 3, Name: 'Ross' })
                                        ]);
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

I have no doubt that this solution could be improved upon,  feel free to pass on better solutions/tips. Frankly I think this kind of option should be baked into Knockout.